# Android Splashcreen and MainActivity: app icon not centered

Tags: android, splash-screen

I am having a hard time to have the app logo being correctly centered when transitioning from a SplashScreen to the MainActivity.

For the SplashScreen, I am using the following : a theme with a background XML made of a layer list :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:opacity="opaque">

    <item android:drawable="@color/blue_accent"/>

    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_logo_big"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

The MainActivity theme declared in the Manifest is `R.style.AppThem_Launcher` with uses the above XML :

```
<style name="AppTheme.Launcher">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_background</item>
</style>
```

Then in MainActivity `onCreate()` the following does the trick :

```
// do some heavy stuff, like dependancy injection, lib initialisation etc,
setTheme(R.style.AppTheme); 
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Doing this is perfect. No need for a SplashActivity. The logo and the primary color are displayed during the whole launch time and initialisation time.

Anyway, my problem is with the logo position. Indeed, my MainActivity layout has a centered ImageView with the same logo drawable but positions do not match. I believe that for the splashscreen, the logo is centered based on the whole screen (system bar included) while for the MainActivity it isn't (system bar not included).

I tried various tricks like adding the half of the system bar height to Y value of the logo at runtime, but to no avail : **it's either a bit too low, or a bit too high.**

Is there a way to get the position of the bitmap in the splashscreen ? Is there a way to have both logo the same exact position ?

Comment: Have you found the solution or workaround for this?

Comment: I am also having same issue @TarasKohut. Please keep posted if anyone found any solution.

Comment: Did you figure this out, @Mackovich?

Comment: @paul-woitaschek I am afraid, no. And with the democratization of the notch (+ official support in Android 9), this issue will be harder to resolve.

Comment: I have the same Problem

Answer (score 0):

What finally works for me is that I added in my Activity Layout

```
android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
```

Then my icons art at the same position.

Comment: Not a perfect solution at all. For me this value is 12 dp and I can't fidure out where it comes from

Comment: UPD: figured it out, formula is (statusBarHeight - navBarHeight) / density